# Pycharm terminal does not use the updated /bin/bash shell on macOS

Tags: pycharm

I had already run `chsh -s /bin/bash` and the changes have taken effect for `Terminal` and `iTerm[2]` but not in `PyCharm` .  I even closed `PyCharm` and ran that command directly in the included Terminal (which has decided it wants to continue using `zsh`):

```
% chsh -s /bin/bash
Changing shell for stephenboesch.
Password for stephenboesch: 
chsh: no changes made
% echo $SHELL
/bin/zsh
stephenboesch@stephenb cscp %
```

So how can `Pycharm` terminal be convinced to switch over to `/bin/bash` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set which shell to use in PyCharm's terminal under `Tools > Terminal > Shell path` in settings.

Changes to your default shell will also be detected automatically if you log-out and log back in again.